# Pivot dataframe to switch columns and rows

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I wish to use the pivotlonger function on my df to switch some of the columns but am unable to switch the correct columns rows. The original df is below;

```
Series Name                Country        1997        1998        1999        2000        2001        2002        2003        2004        2005        2006
1  GDP (current US$)                  Spain    5.90E+11    6.19E+11    6.35E+11    5.98E+11    6.28E+11    7.09E+11    9.07E+11    1.07E+12    1.15E+12    1.26E+12
2  GDP (current US$)                 France    1.45E+12    1.50E+12    1.49E+12    1.37E+12    1.38E+12    1.50E+12    1.84E+12    2.12E+12    2.20E+12    2.32E+12
3  GDP (current US$)                 Monaco  2840175545  2934498443  2906093757  2647885849  2718868306  2968987019  3601321065  4137913500  4203084194  4582988333
4  GDP (current US$)                  Italy    1.24E+12    1.27E+12    1.25E+12    1.15E+12    1.17E+12    1.28E+12    1.58E+12    1.81E+12    1.86E+12    1.95E+12
5  GDP (current US$)                Croatia 24091170703 25792876644 23677307509. 21839780971 23273640257 27074550258 34985749883 41958833541 45780237257 50860788253
6  GDP (current US$) Bosnia and Herzegovina  3671816504  4116699437  4685733115  5567405605  5800774707  6728771319  8498560877 10157553968 11222953329 12864610865
```

I have been able to use pivotlonger to get the df below but i want to get a df with countries as columns names rather than rows. See below df for example

```
`Series Name`     Country year  value   
   <chr>             <chr>   <chr> <chr>   
 1 GDP (current US$) Spain   1997  5.90E+11
 2 GDP (current US$) Spain   1998  6.19E+11
 3 GDP (current US$) Spain   1999  6.35E+11
 4 GDP (current US$) Spain   2000  5.98E+11
 5 GDP (current US$) Spain   2001  6.28E+11
 6 GDP (current US$) Spain   2002  7.09E+11
```

looking for something like this;

columns = year spain france monaco italy croatia Bosnia

rows = 1997
1998
1999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pivot_wider(
 df,
 id_cols = c(`Series Name`, year),
 names_from = Country,
 values_from = value
)
```

Comment: I don't doubt that this works but im unable to replicate it (when using my df) getting the error: Error: unexpected input in "  values_from = “"

Comment: I updated the answer and removed quotation marks to use variables directly. Does that work?

Comment: Yes thats perfect, thanks. (forgot to check that myself)